# how to detect the browser

Tags: browser

How can I detect if the browser is an internet explorer or firefox or chrome? Is there an easy way like just using jquery. Because I want to limit the jquery calls if my user agent is internet explorer.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: jQuery.browser has been removed from for the version version 1.9 >

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.browser is deprecated in jQuery since 1.9.

There is a plugin for jQuery that adds this "back" to jquery. You will fid it (and documentation) at https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Install it by adding `<script src="/path/to/jquery.browser.js"></script>` after where you are adding jQuery.

then you can use the following.

```
$.browser.msie; //returns true if ie
$.browser.webkit; //returns true if webkit-browser (Safari, Chrome)
$.browser.mozilla; //returns true if firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Check if IE

```
$.browser.msie ? alert('Internet Explorer') : alert('Not Internet Explorer');
```

Or info for the browser that is accessing page

```
$.each($.browser, function(i, val) {
    $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>").appendTo(document.body);
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/jsKf8/1/)

Comment: deprecated in new jQuery 1.9+

Comment: That's already been pointed out, also this answer if from almost two years ago.